# Cannot implicitly convert type 'IEnumerable<int> to 'int'

Tags: c#, linq

I'm selecting an id from an Linq query so it is an int but when i try to use it again it is giving me the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to 'int'

```
var costcentre = company.CompanyCostCentres
    .Where(cc => cc.Name.ToLower() == CostCentre.ToLower())
    .Select(cid => cid.CompanyCostCentreId)
    .ToList();

if (costcentre != null)
{
    person.PersonInCompanyCostCentres.Add(new Core.Data.PersonInCompanyCostCentre    
    { 
        CompanyCostCentreId = costcentre, 
        UserId = person.UserId, 
        CompanyId = company.CompanyId, 
        RecordCreated = DateTime.Now, 
        RecordModified = DateTime.Now 
    });
}
```

Comment: because costcentre is a list of numbers not 1 number... so you cant assign it to companycostcentreid - even if it is a list of 1..

Comment: Because you're assigning a `List<int>`(`costcentre`) to int property(`CompanyCostCentreId`). I guess you should use `FirstOrDefault`

Comment: Explained your problem and gave you the solution ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem:**

```
var costcentre = company.CompanyCostCentres.Where(cc => cc.Name.ToLower() == 
CostCentre.ToLower()).Select(cid => cid.CompanyCostCentreId).ToList();
```

Returns a list.

```
CompanyCostCentreId = costcentre
```

Tries to assign the list to int

**Solution:**

If `cid.CompanyCostCentreId` is `int`

change

```
var costcentre = company.CompanyCostCentres.Where(cc => cc.Name.ToLower() == 
CostCentre.ToLower()).Select(cid => cid.CompanyCostCentreId).ToList();
```

to

```
var costcentre = company.CompanyCostCentres.Where(cc => cc.Name.ToLower() == 
CostCentre.ToLower()).Select(cid => cid.CompanyCostCentreId).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Then you should handle the possibility that costcentre become a 0 if no result is given.**

Comment: Of course you can, the compiler error specifically says from `IEnumerable<int>` to `int`. You should read the entire question before answering, as well.

Comment: Wow, you should really copy that code into Visual Studio and understand you are completely wrong. It's not what you think it's better, it's how c# works. That **will not return null in any case**

Answer (score 4):

To get the first int from the list of id's, use

```
var costcentres = company.CompanyCostCentres.Where(cc => cc.Name.ToLower() == CostCentre.ToLower()).Select(cid => cid.CompanyCostCentreId);

int costcentre= costcentres.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your costcentre variable is a list. You can use the `.FirstOrDefault(predicate)` method instead of your `.Where(predicate)` to pick out a single item.

See below:

```
var costcentre = company.CompanyCostCentres
    .FirstOrDefault(cc => cc.Name.ToLower() == CostCentre.ToLower())
    .CompanyCostCentreId
```

I have simply changed the Where to FirstOrDefault and removed the .Select() and .ToList()

Comment: True, he can negate the whole list by doing `company.CompanyCostCentres.First(predicate);`

Comment: See my newest edit. We can just change the Where to FirstOrDefault. His select is then unnecessary as we are dealing with a single object rather than a list.